# Estimated standard deviation of a phenotype prevalence that is derived from several studies

Tags: standard-deviation, bioinformatics, genetics

I have allele frequencies from two independent studies

| Study | Number Sample | Allele 1 Freq | Allele 2 Freq | Allele 3 Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | .45 | .475 | .075 |
| B | 34 | .72 | .28 | NA |

The weighted average of each allele frequency is as follows

```
Allele 1 Freq avg: .62

Allele 2 Freq avg: .355

Allele 3 Freq avg: .075
```

The estimated diplotype frequency using hardy Weinberg equilibrium is:

```
Allele 1/Allele 2: 2 * .62 * .355 = 0.4402

Allele 1/Allele 3: 2 * .62 * .075 = 0.093

Allele 2/Allele 3: 2 * .355 * .075 = 0.05325
```

Lets say that I know that:

- Allele 1/Allele 2 and Allele 1/Allele 3 are the only known diplotypes that can produce `phenotype x`
- Allele 2/Allele 3 is the only diplotype known to produce `phenotype y`

Thus I estimate that the frequency of `phenotype x` is `0.4402 + 0.093 = 0.5332` and the frequency of `phenotype y` is `0.05325`.

What I wonder is if I can compute the standard deviation of the phenotype estimates. Usually I would estimate this by `√[p(1-p)/n]` where `n` is sample size and `p` is the population proportion, but I think it is a little weird here because of the missing data, not sure what value to use for `n` or if I can even do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the "NA" in study B might represent a true 0 finding for allele 3, as the proportions of alleles 1 and 2 add up to 1. Is there some reason why you didn't treat that value as 0 instead of ignoring it in the case-weighted allele-frequency averages?

Comment: @EdM I just made this example up, NA represents a study where alleles are not measured at all. Is it possible to use HWE to help me estimate the standard deviation of phenotype x and y? or is this just too far of a stretch. I am at a bit of loss here. I am using these phenotype frequencies but some are based on more studies than others so I want to some to communicate that uncertainty

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts that might help, even if this isn't a complete answer.

First, in small studies it can be surprisingly easy to miss a low-frequency allele. See Gregorius, H.R. (1980) "The probability of losing an allele when diploid genotypes are sampled," [Biometrics 36, 643-652](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2556116). That's particularly the case if there's no information about the population structure of the diplotypes. The implementation of the Gregorius estimate (which I understand to be a worst-case scenario) in the R [`genetics` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=genetics) is 65% for missing an allele at frequency of 0.075 in a sample of 34.

Pay close attention to the design of the studies that you're examining. It's quite possible that the "NA" in a table like you show means that there was no evidence of that allele in the sample, but that it would have been detected if present. In that case you should be including it as a true 0, not ignoring it.

Second, depending on the nature of your data, you might benefit from [multiple imputation](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/), using the information that you have on other characteristics of the data to estimate what would have been found for that missing allele in a situation where it simply wasn't looked for. You generate several probabilistic estimates and pool the results together in a way that incorporates the uncertainty in the imputation. In your case, with the emphasis on the corresponding phenotype estimates, the final pooling would probably be best done on the phenotype level.

Third, in practice in genome-wide studies based on single-nucleotide polymorphisms, a substantial deviation from Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium (HWE) among diplotypes at a locus is sometimes used to remove the locus from consideration. See Section 2.4 of Reed et al. (2015) "A guide to genome-wide association analysis and post-analytic interrogation," [Statist. Med. 34: 3769–3792](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.6605):

> Violations of HWE can be an indication of the presence of population substructure or the occurrence of a genotyping error. While they are not always distinguishable, it is a common practice to assume a genotyping error and remove SNPs for which HWE is violated. If case-control status is available, we limit this filtering to analysis of controls as a violation in cases may be an indication of association.

So, depending on your situation, a working assumption of HWE might be tenable for your phenotype estimates. It would nevertheless seem to be wise also to present the sensitivity of your phenotype prevalence estimates to potential violations of HWE. As an extreme example, what if `phenotype y` from "Allele 2/Allele 3" led to fetal death when combined with some genotype at a different locus? For less extreme possibilities, that might be done with simulation based on different assumptions about co- or counter-occurrence probabilities for the alleles at the locus that are consistent with their overall frequencies.